# Python Selenium GUI to an executable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, exe, executable

I have never made an executable application before but from what I have read its pretty easy, using py2exe to generate the exe.
But I have a GUI that uses Selenium to scrape data from a backend (No I can not use API calls). How do I add chromedriver to the executable? Also, would all the imports go along when using a compiler?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a .py file into an .exe (from my personal experience) all of the imports are included.

I would personally suggest using pyinstaller. I had quite a few problems using py2exe and as a beginner I found pyinstaller much more user-friendly and easier to troubleshoot.

As compiling a file does not alter the .py file, I would suggest getting it to a fully working state and trying it. If it doesn't appear to work or if some of the imports are lost, we can troubleshoot with the error code.

Comment: Thanks for this! Was very easy to make to an exe and works perfect on my computer. But when testing on another computer got 2 errors, Tkinter filenotfound error, and chromedriver executable needs to be in path.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. How large is the program?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/index.html) to create an executable from your python script.

You can install `cx_Freeze` by issuing the command

```
python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade
```

in a `cmd` prompt / terminal.

As far as `tkinter` is concerned, you'll find a working example of how to freeze a `tkinter`-based application with the current version of `cx_Freeze` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52811346/8516269). In the `setup.py` script you find there, you need to replace the name of the `Executable` by the name of your main script. Place this `setup.py`in the same directory than your main script and run

```
python setup.py build
```

from a `cmd` prompt / terminal.

As far as chromedriver is concerned, I've no experience, if you choose this approach and still have problems, please add the exact error message and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.