# Convert python Script which contains GUI interface code(tkinter) along with pandas etc package libraries into .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, py2exe, cx-freeze

Convert a python script file(version 3.7) which contain code realted to GUI(tkinter) and various libraries like pandas etc into an .exe file.

I want an exe file where user double click on it, the gui should open in separate window and process the next instruction in console itself based on user selected option in GUI.

I have written the code in python3 and able to execute it perfectly.

I tried to convert the script file to .exe using pyinstaller and it sucessfully creates the exe file but no output is given.
When i click on the exe it jsut blinks and no output or no gui opened.

trail2: tried with py2exe this time it gave an error like no module pandas available

in the console after setting up the path:

python title.py py2exe  ---->here title.py is the script file name

Error is: ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named 'pandas'

This is what i want:
i want to convert the python script file which contain GUI code and various libraries to an .exe file

result should be:
when user click on exe file, as per code a gui should open and process the next instructions in the console as per user selection in gui.

Main problem in only with how to convert python script file which contain gui and various other libraries like pandas to exe file.

Comment: You have to create [a setup.py file](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) with py2exe

Comment: You have added the cx-freeze tag to your question but do not mention cx_Freeze in the question body: please remove the tag if it is irrelevant, or add the relevant information to the question body otherwise.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52811346/8516269) for a working example of how to freeze a tkinter-based application with the current version of cx_Freeze.